# Why does a date generated after another can appear to be before the previous one in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp

I got the following code

```
    timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(timestamp))
    now = datetime.utcnow()

    if now < timestamp:
        return False
```

Sometimes, it returns `False`. But only sometimes.

A `print` just at the condition check gives me this:

```
now 2013-02-28 18:02:57.015817
timestamp 2013-02-28 18:02:57.020000
```

So it seems that the timestamp is playing "Back to the future" for a few milisecs.

The timestamp is generated from a `(datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()` in a previous call.

I got this result a in unit test ran by py.test in a Django project on a recent Ubuntu.

My current solution is to make everything a timestamp, tuncate the milisecs and compare. It's ok for me to do so. I'm just curious to understand why does this happen ?

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @MarkRansom: The C implementation uses an int for the microseconds component.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the `total_seconds` call returns a float.

Comment: The reason I'm calling float on the timestamp is that it's been casted ton a a string between the two calls.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Sure, but that float is then converted to a `datetime` object. It's those objects that are being compared, and according to e-satis' print statement they only differ in the microsecond component.

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this? No luck on python 2.7, win 64

Comment: @danodonovan: I certainly can't.

Comment: @danodonovan, I think as usual the problem is in the details left out of the question - the timestamp is being converted from a float to a string, and that conversion is almost certainly where the rounding is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess: a `datetime` is exact and stores the number of microseconds as a separate integer.  But a `float` is fuzzy; it's stored as a binary fraction, and you might get slight rounding.

But you shouldn't be using `total_seconds` to convert to a timestamp.  Do this instead:

```
import calendar
timestamp = calendar.timegm(datetime.utcnow().timetuple())
```

This will, conveniently enough, only ever return an integer anyway.

Comment: The microseconds are stored as an int.

Comment: Yeah that's probably it. When i'm converting the datetime object (which doesn't have rounding problem since ms are stored as int like martijn says) to a float, I opening the door too rounding problems. Stupid me.

Comment: @e-satis the hint is in a comment you left on the question. You do a conversion from `float` to `string` which will round the timestamp to a certain number of digits.

Comment: the issue is *not* `.total_seconds()`. As @MarkRansom said: `float` -> `str` looses the precision, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15462805/4279). btw, even for `datetime.max` [`.total_seconds()` is more precise than the `calendar`-based solution](http://ideone.com/EY3QWp).

Answer (score 0):

You're casting `timestamp` with a `float` - could this rounding operation occasionally round upwards, and so you hit the `now < timestamp` conditional?

Comment: But the OP prints the `str()` version of the two compared datetime objects, and thus we can see that they are equal apart from the microseconds attribute.

Comment: `total_seconds` already returns a float, see the documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The other people talking about rounding issues when casting dates from floats probably have the correct answer.

I suspect the problem is that you are confusing variable name scope in your code. Instead of:

```
timestamp = (datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(timestamp ))
now = datetime.utcnow()
```

try refactoring to something like this:

```
ts = (datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(ts))
now = datetime.utcnow()
```

And see what happens. There's really no good reason for `timestamp` to go through those different transformations like that, and it'll be easier to debug exactly what's happening 
this way.

Comment: timestamp is a variable passed as a fonction argument, is not contained in any kind of closure, and the dynamic nature of python make the replacement legit. I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The core reason is `float -> str` conversion that is not shown in your question (timestamp to a string). Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import count


def main():
    for i in count():
        timestamp = (datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        s_timestamp = str(timestamp)
        dt_from_str = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(s_timestamp))
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        if now < dt_from_str:
            dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
            for o in [now, dt_from_str, dt, timestamp, s_timestamp, i]:
                print(repr(o))
            break

main()
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 17, 15, 52, 38, 355006)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 17, 15, 52, 38, 360000)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 17, 15, 52, 38, 355003)
1363535558.355003
'1363535558.36'
688
```

Notice that `dt` (`datetime(2013, 3, 17, 15, 52, 38, 355003)`) is less than `now` (`datetime(2013, 3, 17, 15, 52, 38, 355006)`) as it should and the rounding occurs in `str(timestamp)` expression (`'1363535558.36'`).